# Documenting Powershell module: how specific should you be about the ouput type?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell module with some cmdlets that output custom objects. I am not sure about how to document them.

What do I put `.OUTPUTS` section? (I'm using PlatyPS so in my case it is `## OUTPUTS` in an .md file, but same difference)

Should I be really precise and actually put
'Either of `ReferencedAssembly.Foo.ThingieX` or `ReferencedAssembly.Foo.ThingieY` or `ReferencedAssembly.Foo.ThingieZ`'

Or simply put `System.Object`?

As a developer, I would like to know all details. To the casual end-user, it does not matter what the cmdlet outputs. He may go 'I have no idea what those scary things are, better not touch this cmdlet'.

What do you think?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you're working with?

Comment: from what i understand, the `.OUTPUTS` section of `CommentBasedHelp` is strictly a bit of polite info. even the `[OutputType()]` attribute is mostly meaningless. ///// so, add it if you want to be complete ... but most will leave it off since it doesn't do very much at all. the few times i have seen it used, i was just to document something that might not be obvious ... but was considered significant enuf to add to the help system.

Comment: I hope the linked post provides enough guidance. /cc @Lee_Dailey,